# Latin words for “engineer”

Tags: contemporary-latin, medieval-latin, new-latin, word-request

While I was reading *La révolution industrielle au Moyen Âge* (*The Medieval Machine: The Industrial Revolution of the Middle Ages*) by Jean Gimpel, I’ve read:

> In the old texts, James of Saint George is called the *machoun*, or sometimes *machinator*, sometimes also *ingeniator*.
>
> (p.114 of the French edition)

And later:

> The expression *ingeniator* was generally reserved for architects who specialized in building military installations.
>
> (p. 115, *ibid.*)

Machoun seems to be old French as I’ve found the expression “Mestre Jakes de Seint Jorge le Machoun”.
Traupman translates *engineer* by *machinator*. It seems that in most languages the term for *engineer* derives from French *ingénieur* which derives from Latin *ingeniator* (En. *engineer*, Ge. *Ingenieur*, Sp. *ingeniero*, It. *ingegnere*…).

Do you know other Latin words for *engineer*? When possible, providing an history of the use of those words would be perfect.
Thanks!

Comment: My dictionary suggests *ingeniarius*, but I think it was coined by analogy to the words in other languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Besides *machinator*, I found two words for *engineer* in classical Latin that are primarily directed towards the devising of buildings and fortifications.

- [aedificator](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daedificator) A builder, derived from *aedes* (house, temple)
- [munitor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmunitor) An engineer of fortifications, derived from *moenia* (walls).

An [architectus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Darchitectus), besides being an architect, could also represent someone who actually is making something as a master-builder.

I still think *machinator* covers the meaning of a modern engineer best, because it describes a maker and inventor of machines, for example weaponry:

> inventor ac machinator bellicorum tormentorum (Liv. 24, 34)

Or stages:

> machinatores, qui pegmata per se surgentia excogitant (Sen. Ep. 88, 19)

As you can see in the first example, *inventor* can also be used for someone who invents something physical.

Comment: Thx, that’s interesting. I’ve found this article about *architectus* https://www.jstor.org/stable/2856447?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the Vatican dictionary for recent and new words uses:

> doctor machinarius

It can be found [here](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html), as a translation from the Italian word *ingegnere*.

Comment: I don’t think it is a perfect translation insofer as an engineer doesn’t necessarly have a phD.

Comment: *Machinarius* is what I was taught, but I can't recall the published source. It seems quite apt to me, with or without the *doctor*.